# Renaming files in Shell script for loop

Tags: bash, macos, shell, file, renaming

I run OS X and have multiple photos and started naming them `xyz-100.jpg`, `xyz-101.jpg`, `xyz-102.jpg` up to `xyz-402.jpg` and now want to rename them by basically reducing the number by 99, making it `xyz-1.jpg`, `xyz-2.jpg` up to `xyz-303.jpg`.

I know I can use the `mv` command for that, but I don't seem to be able to implement a variable into the filename, such as `xyz-$reduced.jpg`. How can I properly do that?

Comment: Try xyz-${reduced}.jpg  This will help variable expansion know what to expand and what not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend you move them to another directory, since otherwise you run the risk of confusion if something bad happens midway through.  So try:

```
mkdir tmp
for ((n=100; n<=402; n++)); do 
  ln xyz-$n.jpg tmp/xyz-$((n-99)).jpg
done
```

That should give you the files you want inside `tmp/`. Then you can move that directory where you'd like and remove the old files.  If you're not familiar with `ln`, think of it as half of a `mv`.  Basically `mv foo bar` is the same as `ln foo bar; rm foo`.  By linking the newly named files in a subdirectory, you won't have any conflicts trying to figure out if file 150 is really 150 or if it is the renamed 249.  Also, instead of iterating through the existing files and trying to parse the number, just use `jot` to generate the names that you know you want.

Comment: @mklement0 asks in an edit "why not use seq?"  The OP mentioned that he was using OSX (although I think the marketing folks have returned to calling in MacOS!) so I thought `jot` more appropriate.  Unfortunately, I'm fairly certain that neither `jot` nor `seq` is standardized, but any method for doing the loop will do.  Probably better to do `for ((n=100; n<=402; n++)); do `

Comment: `for ((n=100; n<=402; n++)); do` is indeed the best approach. Indeed, neither `jot` nor `seq` are POSIX-mandated utilities. `jot` is specific to BSD-like platforms, including the recently rechristened macOS (note the lowercase "m"); by contrast , similar - but not identical - implementations of `seq` can be found on both Linux and BSD/macOS, and that's what prompted my suggestion: if it's easy to make an answer work on additional platforms, future readers may benefit.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work.  but i'm not sure how you're obtaining the number of files.  you could also cat the output of another file that list filenames to the same effect as this.  but this should get you started

```sh
num_array=(1 2 3 4 5)

for i in "${!num_array[@]}"; do
       mv -i ./"myfile_${i}.jpg" /somehwere_else
done
```

Comment: You should *always* use `mv -i` for bulk moves like this; otherwise if there's a naming conflict, one file can silently and irreversibly overwrite another.